# Issues with Sharp MX-M503N printer

Tags: printing

I have tried repeatedly to install CUPS drivers (all four versions for Ubuntu; Sharp-MX-M503F-ps-jp.ppd; Sharp-MX-M503N-ps.ppd; Sharp-MX-M503N-ps-jp.ppd; Sharp-MX-M503U-ps.ppd), one after the other. CUPS sees the printer, I can network ping the printer. I came across a filter failure, re-installed a driver listed above, and now it says "job completed," however, nothing happens. I can hear the printer "rev up" like its preparing for a job, but nothing happens.

I'd love to get this printer set up. It's ultra frustrating because I work for a local auto dealer and need my laptop to print information for my customers and I can't do that without a workable printer.

I did have an issue when Ubuntu found generic drivers that printed off multiple pages in a row with one line of wingdings, and that has since been fixed.

Thank you all kindly for the help

Comment: This device requires some sort of optional addon to print PostScript. Is that present?

Comment: I was unable to find a PostScript PPD file in any of the driver databases online, the ones I found were from directly searching the printer make and model.

Comment: You have misundrstood my question. Any PostScript PPD file is only of use if the printer is a PostScript printer. My understanding of the printer's brochure is that PostScript does not come as standard but is an option, maybe to be purchased from Sharp. I was asking whether you knew for certain whether the printer is definitely capable of printing PostScript.

Comment: My apologies for the misunderstanding. I am unaware if the printer is capable of printing postscript and I'm not sure how to find out.

Answer (score 0):

To test whether a printer will deal with a PostScript file, such a file may be sent **directly** to the printer. An IP address for the printer is needed; we will call this IP_ADDRESS. Get a small PostScript file and do

```
netcat IP_ADDRESS 9100 < YOUR_POSTSCRIPT_FILE
```

substituting, of course.

Does YOUR_POSTSCRIPT_FILE print successfully? If so, we can progress from there.

Suppose there isn't any printing. This implies the printer does not understand PostScript. However, the printer appears to support PCL. About the best I can give you here is to set up a print queue with

```
lpadmin -p testq -v socket://IP_ADDRESS:9100 -E -m drv:///sample.drv/generpcl.ppd
```

and try printing with

```
lp -d testq /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Comment: It does not. The printer again acts like it's going to print, as it "spools up" but then, again, does nothing. CUPS says "idle - filter failed"

Comment: I cannot see why CUPS would have anything to say; it is not involved in the transaction.  The netcat command does not use CUPS to send the test file.

Comment: @mcmfan92 I have added to my answer.